# Windows 2000 - cannot connect

Tags: windows-2000

My client computer has windows 2000 my server computer is windows XP should they be able to communicate?  My server says "waiting for client" my client says "connecting to SC25" which is the servers name but they do not connect

Comment: Are they both in the same workgroup?

Comment: What are you using to connect?  Please list steps and software.

Comment: @Moab: AFAIK, the only purpose of "workgroups" is to group computers in the "browse lists" used by NetBIOS _name resolution_. They do not otherwise affect communication between computers.

Comment: I know, but with the limited info in the post, doing this can help.